# How to extract data between two different xml tags

Tags: text-processing, xml

I have looked but haven't been able to find anyone else with the same sort of problem I have.

I have an xml file like this:

```
<ID>1</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed><ID>2</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed><ID>3</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed><ID>4</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed>
```

Basically a whole bunch of data all on one line, no line breaks.
I need to extract the info (preferably just as-is with tags intact) between a specific < ID> tag (eg < ID>2 )and the very next < /dateAccessed> tag. I have about 50 files to check for a particular ID and the following related data. I get that this is not standard, there is no nesting.

I originally tried to do this using grep and sed, but I just get the whole file returned, which seems odd to me. Can't I just treat this like a text file?

EDIT:

I didn't realise the formatter removed text that was in enclosing < and > , so after re-reading my question this morning, I realised it's asking something completely different. 
TL;DR
I need what is between a specific value between ID tags and the next closing DateAccessed tag. Not between the same opening and closing tags, ie between ID and /ID

So I can get something like this result:

```
<ID>2</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed>
```

Comment: I can't help but feel this is the "wrong question". If you're working with XML files you should really be using an XML parser (such as `xmlstarlet`). I appreciate this won't give you an unbalanced segment, and so is not a suitable answer to your question as asked. But trying to treat XML as text will almost certainly lead to unintended consequences down the road. It's not a good place to be. Really.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, your data isn't well-formed XML and it isn't completely clear what the structure of your document is, e.g. judging by your example data, it looks like you have no nested elements - is that really the case?

With that caveat in mind, here's a Python script that uses the [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) parsing library to do what you want (i.e. it produces the desired output data for the given example input data):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: ascii
"""extract.py

Extract everything between two XML tags
in a (possibly poorly formed) XML document."""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

# Set the opening tag name and value
opening_name = "ID"
opening_text = "2"

# Set the closing tag name
closing_name = "dateAccessed"

# Get the XML data from a file and instantiate a BeautifulSoup parser
# We add a root node because the input data is missing a root
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as xmlfile:
    xmldoc = "<root>" + xmlfile.read() + "</root>"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xmldoc, 'xml')

# Iterate through the elements of the XML data and collect
# all of the elements inbetween the opening and closing tags
elements = []
match = False
for e in soup.find_all():
    if match is True:
        elements.append(str(e))
        if e.name==closing_name:
            break
    else:
        try:
            if e.name==opening_name and e.text==opening_text:
                match = True
                elements.append(str(e))
        except AttributeError:
            pass

# Output the results on a single line
print("".join(elements))
```

You would run it something like this:

```bsh
python extract.py data.xml
```

For your given example data:

```
<ID>1</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed><ID>2</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed><ID>3</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed><ID>4</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed>
```

It produces the following output:

```
<ID>2</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the XML document actually has a root tag (your XML does not and is therefore not well formed), then you may use XMLstarlet like this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//ID[. = 2]' \
    -c . -c './following-sibling::*[position()<5]' -nl file.xml
```

For the given data (modified to insert `<root>` at the start and `</root>` at the end), this would return

```
<ID>2</ID><data>asdf</data><data2>asdf</data2><dataX>asdf</dataX><dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed>
```

The XMLstarlet query selects any `ID` node whose contents is `2` (`-m '//ID[. = 2]'`).  For each of these nodes (only one in the given data), it returns a copy of the node itself (`-c .`) along with a copy of the following five sibling nodes (`-c './following-sibling::*[position()<5]'`), ending the output by inserting a newline (`-nl`).

The `<root>` start and end tags could be inserted into the document itself, or be handed to XMLstarlet like so:

```
{ echo '<root>'; cat file.xml; echo '</root>'; } |
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//ID[. = 2]' \
    -c . -c './following-sibling::*[position()<5]' -nl
```

Answer (score -1):

## Grep

```
grep -oE '<data>[^<]*</data>' yourxmlfile
```

## Bash

```
tag='data'
tL="<$tag>" tR="</$tag>"
xml=$(< yourxmlfile)
while case $xml in *"$tL"* ) :;; * ) break;; esac; do
  t1=${xml#*"$tL"} t2=${t1%%"$tR"*} xml=${t1#*"$tR"}
  echo "${tL}${t2}${tR}"
done
```

## Perl

```
perl -lne "print for/<$tag>.*?<\/$tag>/g" yourxmlfile
```

## Sed

```
sed -e "
  s|<$tag>|\n&|
  s/.*\n//
  s|</$tag>|&\n|
  /\n/P;D
" yourxmlfile
```

## Output

```
 <data>asdf</data>
 <data>asdf</data>
 <data>asdf</data>
 <data>asdf</data>
```

Answer (score -2):

if you want to extract the ID value, and i assume ID always comes as first tag, then you can use this

```
awk -F"[<>]" '{print $3}' input.txt
```

if you want to search for specific tag, then try this awk command. you need to change the value of input=ID

```
awk -F"[<>]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~input){print $(i+1);next}}' input=ID input.txt
```

Answer (score -4):

provided XML has no line breaks.
why don't you try inserting \n between >< which will make the XML in standard format

Example:-
i have created a file called stack with the given xml.

below is the sed operation to introduce line breaks.

```
 cat stack|sed -e 's/></>\n</g'

<ID>2</ID>
<data>asdf</data>
<data2>asdf</data2>
<dataX>asdf</dataX>
<dateAccessed>somedate</dateAccessed>
```

now you can access the tags you want